# Swap two Nodes of LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

**You have been given a singly linked list of integers along with two integers, 'i,' and 'j.' Swap the nodes that are present at the 'i-th' and 'j-th' positions.

My code is as below, can you suggest an efficient alternate way?**

```
public static LinkedListNode<Integer> swapNodes(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int i, int j) {
        //Your code goes here
        LinkedListNode<Integer> temp=head;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> temp1=head;
        LinkedListNode<Integer> tempo=new LinkedListNode<Integer>(0);
        int beg=0, end=0;
   
       for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
        {      
            temp=temp.next;
           
        }

        for(int y=0;y<j;y++)
        {
            temp1=temp1.next;
        
        }
   
       tempo.data= temp.data;
        temp.data= temp1.data;
        temp1.data=tempo.data;
        
        
        return head;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: more efficient is an opinion question. Tell us what specifically doesn't work, what is the error message and what you have tried to fix it

Comment: For starters, you can only loop once over the linked list instead of twice

Comment: Your code is not doing what you are saying in the first sentence: *"Swap the nodes"*, which is also reflected in the name of the function. But your code is swapping values, not nodes. It also has a dangling brace.

Comment: find the max of (i,j) , and use only that to traverse to that node, while going to it, the lesser position node can be got hold of. this is the efficient way. the problem says swap the nodes, if data swapping alone is acceptable is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more efficient you can remove one of the for loops. first add another variable named `LinkedListNode<Integer> t=head;`, then you can first check between i and j and see which one is bigger and do a for loop for that.

```
LinkedListNode<Integer> t=head;

int counter = (i > j) ? i : j;
for(int x=0;x<counter;x++)
{      
    t = t.next;
    if(counter == i-1){   
       temp=t.next;
    } 
    if(counter == j-1){
       temp1=t.next;
    }       
}
```